# How do I read POST info in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, httpwebrequest

I would like to know how to both send and receive info through HTTP POST requests.

I'm using Ruby v.1.8.7 and rails v.2.3.8.

**EDIT:**

My action's code is the following:

```
require 'net/http'

# get the url that we need to post to
url = URI.parse('http://localhost:3000/ipn/payments')

xml_notificaciones = "<NOTIFICACION><TIPONOTIFICACION>1</TIPONOTIFICACION><OPERACIONES><OPERACION><TIPO>1</TIPO><ID>31548</ID></OPERACION><OPERACION><TIPO>1</TIPO><ID>XA5547</ID></OPEARACION></OPERACIONES></NOTIFICACION>"

# build the params string
post_args1 = { 'NOTIFICACION' => xml_notificaciones }
# send the request
resp, data = Net::HTTP.post_form(url, post_args1)
```

When I execute the above code the page will load for a while until I get `execution expired` message.

I actually have a routes entry for `http://localhost:3000/ipn/payments` url, and is the following:

```
map.received_ipn_payments '/ipn/payments', :controller => 'payments', :action => 'parse_received_data', :method => :post
```

I have a `raise params.inspect` so I know when it works, but nothing so far...

Comment: Your question is a bit ambiguous--do you mean that you want your Rails app to be able to send and receive HTTP requests, presumably not from the browser but to and from an external web service?

Comment: Well, I'll receive some data from a payment method's company which will provide me through POST an XML so I can parse and read the purchases. After reading that, they require my app to send them a request by POST after that, so that's why I need both send and receive data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you trying to post to the same rails application from one of your controllers? If you are running this on a single webrick/mongrel instance, you can only handle one single request. So, if you make a request to your app from your browser, and this request needs to make another request to the same application (which blocks the first one), it'll get stuck and just time out.

I'm not sure why you need your controller to do a second request, it seems to me that you need to run code in another controller/action. You could either redirect to that other controller/action, but that would need a GET request, or move your code from the controller to a model or module and call the appropriate methods from both your controller actions.

Edit:
If you are trying to test your payment processor integration you should be using their testing environment (provided they have one) instead of emulating it in your application. If you really need to write code to emulate the payment process, you should do that in a different application running on its own webrick/mongrel instance. Then you'll be able to make requests to that other application.

Comment: That would be nice if they actually had a test environment, but they don't. So I'm trying to simulate their POST request to my app, so I'm sure I'm handling it correctly. I'll try posting from the browser and I'll let you know.

Comment: I'm guessing it's a concurrency issue as Teoulas suggests. You don't say it explicitly but I believe you're trying to make a POST from inside your controller's action. It's getting stuck and timing out because you're trying to make a request to your app which only handles one request at a time. Follow his suggestions and you should find your problem solved. Also, you should consider using delayed_job to move the third-party request out of your current request-response cycle: you don't want your app to hang because the third-party is down.

Answer (score 2):

To receive the requests into your application, set up a route in `config/routes.rb` for it. See the [Routing Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) for more information. Route it to a controller and then to access the information sent through use the `params` method.

As for sending back data... an alternative to andrea's answer, you could use the [Typhoeus](https://github.com/dbalatero/typhoeus) gem to make the HTTP requests. It's got a really neat syntax to it and I've been using it recently with no worries.

Answer (score 1):

to receiving a post request you have only to create an action in a controller and set the routes with method post.

to send a request you could use something similar

```
require 'net/http'
# get the url that we need to post to
url = URI.parse('http://www.url.com/subscribe')# build the params string
post_args1 = { 'email' => params[:email] }
# send the request
resp, data = Net::HTTP.post_form(url, post_args1)
```

Comment: I've tried this but it keeps loading the page for a while until it says "execution expired", do you know why? I'll edit the post with my code.

Comment: maybe , if the code that you have posted is in the action "parse_received_data" you have an action that recall itself causing a loop. change the uri in  URI.parse('http://localhost:3000/ipn/payments') . sorry if i have misunderstood .